# How to change x-axis labels in ShuildUI based on zoomlevel

Tags: javascript, shieldui

with ShieldUI, when I'm showing weekly scores in a bar chart, I generate 52 values, each with an x-axis label like '2013-49'.

When a user has not zoomed yet, you will see al 52 labels rendered in a big black smudge. I want only 6 labels when zoomed out, and when zooming in I want the additional labels showing.

So I don't want to lose the informational granularity, I only want the displayed granularity improved.

What is the best practice to get the desired behaviour?

Comment: By default the ShieldUI JavaScript Chart limits rendered axisX labels to a reasonable amount, given that the type of the axis is DateTime. Are you using categorical values for the X axis or is it of a dateTime type? As a matter of fact can you show some of your code to see?